# Update column in SQL Server 2008 - SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

If the Customer Transaction type is not mentioned in the database
If the model year is less than or equal to 2 years than the transaction
type should be updated as a Warranty.

Remaining 60 % of the customer data should be updated as Customer
pay and the 40% of the customer data   should be updated as Warranty
randomly on each dealer.

I have a table for Model year table of this structure:

```
SlNo  VehicleNo  ModelYear
----  ---------  ---------
1     AAAD1234   2012
2     VVV023333  2008
3     CRT456     2011
4     MTER6666   2010
```

Is it possible to achieve this using SSIS??

I have tried a query. Please help fix it

```
select 
  vehicleNo, Modelyear,
  case 
      when DATEDIFF(year, ModelYear, GETDATE()) <= 2 then 'Warranty' END,
  case 
      when COUNT(modelyear) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from VehicleModel) > 2 then '100%' end,
  case 
      when COUNT(modelyear) * 40 / (select COUNT(*) from VehicleModel) > 2  then '40%' end
from 
    vehiclemodel
group by 
    vehicleNo, Modelyear
```

Output

```
vehicleNo  Modelyear  (No column name)  (No column name)  (No column name) 
---------  ---------  ----------------  ----------------  ----------------
AAAD1234   2008       NULL              100%              40% 
VVV023333  2010       Warranty          100%              40% 
CRT456     2011       Warranty          100%              40%
MTER6666   2012       Warranty          100%              40%
```

Comment: 0 down vote favorite
share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]
 

If the Customer Transaction type is not mentioned in the database
If the model year is less than or equal to 2 years than the transaction type should be updated as a Warranty.

Remaining 60 % of the customer data should be updated as Customer pay and the 40% of the customer data should be updated as Warranty randomly on each dealer. Thanks

Comment: I mean can you edit your query and show a output table?

Comment: vehicleNo Modelyear (No column name) (No column name) (No column name)
AAAD1234             2008          NULL                 100%       40%
VVV023333           2010          Warranty                100%       40%
CRT456                  2011          Warranty                100%       40%
MTER6666            2012          Warranty                100%       40%

Comment: I edited your question with the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly are you trying to do with SSIS? Where are you moving data from and where are you inserting it to?

If you only need to run this query you don't need SSIS. You can do this logic in SQL.
If you need to insert this into another table or database I would also do the calculation on SQL (like you just did) and use it as source to an OleDBSourtce component and then insert it into your destination.

I think you have to provide more information so we can help you

Comment: I want to check for the above mentioned conditions and then update the Transaction Type column in the Transaction table as Warranty if the vehicle was purchased before 2 years.
the remaining vehicles that are > 2 years will be counted and out of it 60% will be updated as customer pay and remaining 40% as others

Comment: humm ok but I dont understand why you need SSIS. It seems that you can do everything using SQL queries. Whats exactly is the issue? Isnt your query working? If not can you post your table structure?

Comment: The business rules are part of SSIS package so thought, there might be a way to solve the problem using SSIS components.If it can be done only using a query kindly help with one...Thanks

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VehicleModel](
 [SlNo] [int] NULL,
 [VehicleNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [ModelYear] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]